# Multicast WCCP with Squid + multiple routers

Tags: networking, server, proxy, router

Currently I'm building a lab with multiple routers and two Ubuntu servers as proxies. Here's the topology:

[image: topology]

What is happening right now is that the traffic is already redirected to the proxy, but when the proxy sends the traffic back to Host 3 through another router it's labelled as invalid request, because the router doesn't recognize that.

I have been looking over the internet and in books for a few months and have one clue, that is to to enable multicast on Squid (or Ubuntu?) to announce its presence to the routers, so when Host 3 requests the web page to the internet its traffic will be redirected to the proxy, and then the proxy will meet the request whether the traffic through multiple router.

Comment: The functionality to announce to the routers is WCCP but the router has to be Cisco with that technology